# Converting timestamp float to datetime in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I have timestamps as floats, which I want to convert to datetime objects.
Example:
20050101.47916667 would be the time 2005-01-01 11:30:00

Using the code:

```
import datetime
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(20050101.47916667))
```

Results in the output:

```
1970-08-21 02:28:21.479167
```

How can I convert my float to the right datetime?

Edit: My full code is the following, as I am trying to create a timeseries with the date in the right format on the x-axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,1,squeeze=True)

a = Dataset('control1.nc')
a2 = Dataset('affor1.nc')
a3 = Dataset('control2.nc')
a4 = Dataset('affor2.nc')

my_time = a.variables['Times'][:]   
V10 = a.variables['V10'][:,0,0]

my_time2 = a2.variables['Times'][:]
V10_2 = a2.variables['V10'][:,0,0]

my_time3 = a3.variables['Times'][:]
V10_3 = a3.variables['V10'][:,0,0]

my_time4 = a4.variables['Times'][:]
V10_4 = a4.variables['V10'][:,0,0]

x1 = my_time
x2 = my_time2
x3 = my_time3
x4 = my_time4
y1 = V10
y2 = V10_2
y3 = V10_3
y4 = V10_4

axs[0].plot(x1,y1, marker='', color='red', linewidth=1, label='Control WGP2')
axs[0].plot(x2,y2, marker='', color='blue', linewidth=1, label='Afforestation WGP2')
axs[1].plot(x3,y3, marker='', color='magenta', linewidth=1, label='Control WGP4')
axs[1].plot(x4,y4, marker='', color='black', linewidth=1, label='Afforestation WGP4')

axs[0].legend()
axs[1].legend()
axs[0].set_title('January 2005',loc='center')
axs[0].set_xlabel('Date')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Date')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Wind gusts (m/s)')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Wind gusts (m/s)')

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.label_outer()

plt.show()
```

Both variables (V10 and time) are arrays, example:

```
[20050101.47916667 20050102.47916667 20050103.47916667 20050104.47916667
 20050105.47916667 20050106.47916667 20050107.47916667 20050108.47916667
 20050109.47916667 20050110.47916667 20050111.47916667 20050112.47916667
 20050113.47916667 20050114.47916667 20050115.47916667 20050116.47916667
 20050117.47916667 20050118.47916667 20050119.47916667 20050120.47916667
 20050121.47916667 20050122.47916667 20050123.47916667 20050124.47916667
 20050125.47916667 20050126.47916667 20050127.47916667 20050128.47916667
 20050129.47916667 20050130.47916667 20050131.47916667]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could parse the part before the decimal separator to a `datetime` object and add the day fraction as a `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

f = 20050101.47916667
dtobj = datetime.strptime(str(int(f)), '%Y%m%d') + timedelta(days=f-int(f))
# datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 1, 11, 30, 0, 429)
```

if you have to convert lists of those floats, you could make it a function and use a list comprehension:

```
def flt_2_dtobj(f):
    return datetime.strptime(str(int(f)), '%Y%m%d') + timedelta(days=f-int(f))

l = [20050101.47916667, 20050102.47916667, 20050103.47916667]

l_dt = [flt_2_dtobj(f) for f in l]

# [datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 1, 11, 30, 0, 429),
#  datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 2, 11, 30, 0, 429),
#  datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 3, 11, 30, 0, 429)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`date.fromtimestamp()` expects a POSIX timestamp, as noted in the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). The float timestamp format I have never seen before and you will probably have to parse manually.

Edit:
You can parse the `year-month-day` by casting the timestamp to an `int` and then to a `string`, `str(int(timestamp))`. From there all you have to do is reformat the string into whatever format you want. I expect the decimal portion is a fraction of a day? If that is the case some simple algebra can convert it to a 24 hour time.